# How do I prove the circumference of the Koch snowflake is divergent?

Tags: limits, proof-writing, fractals

How do I prove that the circumference of the Koch snowflake is divergent?

[image]

Let's say that the line in the first picture has a lenght of $3cm$.
Since the middle part ($1cm$) gets replaced with a triangle with sidelenghts of $1cm$ each 
we can assume that the circumference increases by the $\frac{4}{3}$-fold.

I guess to calculate the circumference the following term should work, no?

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{3cm\cdot\frac{4}{3}^n}$

I know that the limit of the circumference is divergent ( $+\infty$).

I also know that a divergent sequence is defined as :

[image]

But how do I prove syntactically and mathematically correct that the sequence diverges to $+\infty$ ?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977793/koch-snowflake-versus-pi-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the binomial theorem to write

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac43\right)^n&=\left(1+\frac13\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\left(\frac13\right)^k1^{n-k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\left(\frac13\right)^k\tag{1}\\\\
&\ge\binom{n}0\left(\frac13\right)^0+\binom{n}1\left(\frac13\right)^1\\\\
&=1+\frac{n}3
\end{align*}$$

for $n\ge 1$, since all terms of $(1)$ are positive.

Comment: i almost got it but could you explain what´s after (1) ?

Comment: @ViktorG: By $(3)$ do you mean the inequality step?

Comment: yes that´s what i meant

Comment: @ViktorG: The summation in the previous line expands to $$\binom{n}0\left(\frac13\right)^0+\binom{n}1\left(\frac13\right)^1+ \binom{n}2\left(\frac13\right)^2+ \ldots+\binom{n}{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)^{n-1}+ \binom{n}n\left(\frac13\right)^n\;.$$ All terms are positive, so if I throw away some terms, what’s left is $\le$ this sum. I threw away all but the first two terms: the full sum is $$\ge \binom{n}0\left(\frac13\right)^0+\binom{n}1\left(\frac13\right)^1\;.$$

Comment: I see :) Thank you for the fast answer :)

Comment: @ViktorG: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$\frac{4^n}{3^n}=L\quad\Rightarrow\quad n=\log_{4/3}L$$